# Blank Values in Excel Data Validation drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I dont know how many values will be present from Cell A1 to A65555.
I have B1 which is set with data validation based on A column as below
    A1:A65555

Values are present in A column upto 10 rows. (from A1 to A10)

But when i click B1, it shows empty values along with A1 to A10.
I want all not null values of A column to be listed in B1.

Note: i have ticked the option "Ignore Blank cells" in Data validation setting.
or Any one let me know how to set data validation through VBA ?

Comment: Also, the 'Ignore Blank cells' setting in the Data Valdition dialog box is used to prevent the restricted cells (those on which the Data Validation is applied, in your case `B1` I guess) from giving 'Invalid Data' errors when the cells are left empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you will not have gaps in column A, just some amount of blank rows at bottom of column (as in data will always be A1:AN where 1 < N <= 65555)

Formulas => Define Name

enter some name (like ValidationList)

Use this as your formula `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$1"),0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)`

Then define data validation list as the the name you entered (and check ignore blanks again so it doesn't give errors when you haven't selected anything)

Comment: Curiosity - what changes need be made if there were blank cells in `A1:AM` where M is the last row filled row? I know how to do it in VBA, but is there some non-VBA way?

Comment: it MAY be possible but it would be pretty messy to handle arbitrary size and # of gaps. I think VBA would be easier for that scenario. for the OP's need the formula works great.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code that inserts data validation by vba programmatically and ignores blanks, so the list will be easier to scroll.

Validation in Sheets("Whatsup_msg") column J, from Source Sheets("Phones_Emails") column A.

```
Sub ValidateNonBlanks()
Dim lastRowCombo As Long
Dim lastRowSource As Long
Dim rangeSource As Range
Dim rangeCombo  As Range

lastRowCombo = 150
lastRowSource = Sheets("Phones_Emails").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Set rangeCombo = Sheets("Whatsup_msg").Range("J4:J" & lastRowCombo)
Set rangeSource = Sheets("Phones_Emails").Range("A4:A" & lastRowSource)

With rangeCombo.Validation
    .Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:="=Phones_Emails!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowSource
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```