# Excel - Data Validation blank items in the list, dependency list

Tags: excel

We are looking to create a dependent list based on 2 sheets as described below.
Sheet 1:
col A:  Need to choose a value from drop down referring to col country in sheet 2
col B: Need to country corresponding cities available in sheet2

Sheet 2:
col Country: USA  UK  India Australia
col USA cities:  Boston Chicago Seattle SanDiego
col UK cities: London Manchester Edinburg Glasglow
col India cities: Mumbai Delhi Kochin
col Aus Cities: Victoria Melbourne Sydney

Typical example:
If we choose the country from drop down as USA in colA (sheet1), then the colB (sheet1) needs to show all the USA cities from "col USA cities".

I have tried using [Blank Values in Excel Data Validation drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242399/blank-values-in-excel-data-validation-drop-down-list) with data validation for col B as =Indirect($A2 & "list") (after naming the cities as lists such as USAlist, UKlist etc) but didn't help.

Also, any idea how to solve the blanks shown by the list in this scenarios?

Comment: Formula `=Indirect($A2 & "list")` is okay. Show us a screenshot of sheet2. How data are structured in sheet2 and also show name manager, how you defined named ranges?

Comment: I think problem is in naming of ranges.